# How to perform lookup to return multiple columns and rows multiple matches in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to create a view for a sales report and below shown images gives the representation of the same. 
The table in image 1 is the data table and I would like to create a new with lookups or Index match options. 
[image]

The expected view of the data is as shown in below picture.

The name column is being used as a filter.
[image]

Comment: Have a look at the `SUMIFS` function.

Comment: Hi the issue is not with summing, most of my real data is text. The data provided here is a dummy representation.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Did you try to use `Pivot Table` (`Insert > Tables > PivotTable`)?  I think this is a better tool for you to try for your case.

See the screenshot above, and drag & drop the fields to the places that shows in the pic.  You may need to tweak a little bit here and there but this should get you start.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I have tried pivot tables and it doesn't work as I have many more columns to represent below the region.

Comment: I see.  Agreed that Pivot Table sometimes is not so easy to figure out certain structure.  But you should be able to get it if you keep trying.

Answer (score 0):

A pivot table is the way to go here.

The capabilities of a pivot are huge so the numbers of regions you have shouldn't present an issue.

Use your main data as a base and ensure there are no empty header cells in the pivot range and you should be able to produce the format you require.

Good luck